# How to get IOS app to trust localhost for development API

Tags: objective-c, ssl, localhost, trust, self-signed-certificate

Using Visual Studio for Mac, I've created a RESFUL API (developed from API project template), which out of the box outputs a very simple JSON file (i.e. ["value1","value2"]) at the following url: https://localhost:5001/api/values.

So, while running the API on Visual Studio in the background, I'm also running XCode on the same computer; in that I'm developing an app which needs to connect to the API url and output the expected JSON response.

The problem is it continually fails due to a trust error: "TIC SSL Trust Error...NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP Load failed".

From what I've researched, I believe I need to install the self-signed certificate of localhost onto my XCode emulator in order for it to permit the app to trust the url. How do I get access to this localhost certificate?

Or is this even the right way to go?

Code that generates the trust error:

```
// Specify the base url...
static NSString *const API_URL = @"https://localhost:5001";
```

```
// Specify completed url ...
NSString *urlAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/values"];
NSString *urlStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:API_URL]
stringByAppendingString:urlAppend];        

// Specify the URL object that can return JSON, XML, etc....
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];

// Create an NSURLSessionDataTask that does the GET request at the specified URL (using NSURLSession shared session)...
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
              dataTaskWithURL:url
              completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                  // Handle response (output respnose to log window))...
                  NSLog(@"%@", [output initWithData:data  encoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding)] ? : @"no data");
              }];

// Start task ....
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to [Perform Manual Server Trust Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication?language=objc) for the url of the localhost development server (running in the background). This is done by utilizing the [URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession?language=objc) delegate method of your [NSURLSessionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondelegate?language=objc); which will give you the opportunity to match against the localhost url and manually trust it when the session data task begins (before it rejects due to the untrusted self-signed-certificate).

Here's how:

Step 1: Wrap the NSURLSession operations in a class, say "Networking", which implements the NSURLSessionDelegate protocol; and add the delegate method which manually trusts your localhost url (specified as 'DEV_URL').

```
// Networking.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Networking : NSObject <NSURLSessionDelegate>
- (void) fetchContentsOfUrl:(NSURL *)url
                 completion:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error)) completionHandler;
@end
```

```
// Networking.m
#import "Networking.h"

static NSString *const DEV_URL = @"https://localhost:5001";
@implementation Networking
- (void) fetchContentsOfUrl:(NSURL *)url
                 completion:(void (^)(NSData * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    NSURLSession *dataSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [dataSession
                                      dataTaskWithURL:url
                                      completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                                          if (completionHandler == nil) {
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          if (error){
                                              completionHandler(nil, error);
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          completionHandler(data, nil);
                                      }];

    [dataTask resume];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler {

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:DEV_URL];
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host]) {
            NSLog(@"trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
        }
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
@end
```

Step 2: Replace your original code with an instantiation of the Networking class and a call to the fetchContentsOfUrl:completion: method which invokes the NSURLSessionDataTask, as follows:

```
    Networking *networker = [[Networking alloc] init];
    [networker fetchContentsOfUrl:url completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {        
        if (error == nil) {
            NSString *output = [NSString alloc];
            NSLog(@"%@", [output initWithData:data  encoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding)] ? : @"no data");
        }
    }];
```

You're all set!!

Comment: It seems strange to me you would have to code anything to allow this. I would think it is all configuration. Doesn't the app store reject messing with things in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:  At the top of each of your ViewControllers that make any HTTP requests, just under the imports section, add this code:

```
@interface NSURLRequest (DummyInterface)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host;
+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host;
@end
```

Then, down where you are making the request, call this:

```
[request setHTTPBody:data];

[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse  *response = nil;

NSData *data2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```